# Using rules, how do I assign an action to a vbo list item based on its position in the list?

Tags: rules

I'm using rules and conditional rules. I have an action set that is using a vbo list (4 node titles sorted by post date desc) to flag nodes on the list.  This works fine. However, I need to make the first item on the list sticky and the 2nd item on the list promoted.  Then I need to remove sticky and promoted from the 3rd item.

Do I need to be using alert_entity_list:0 and alert_entity_list:1 or should I be looking for alert-list-item:0, etc. ... or am I way off base?

Comment: I figured it out.  For any who are looking for same information, the data selector would be the entity-list:0 for the 1st item in the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I should have posted this as my answer and not as a comment to my question.  As stated above, the answer would be entity-list:0 token.